# Mapping generic type to application of a function on its own type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

After manipulating my Record of definitions and the values from a form, I managed to have a record of a simple object of type:

```js
interface One<T> {
  func: (arg: T) => string;
  value: T;
}
```

As this come in multiple flavors (key based on a radio button), I have a record with each different key map to a different "T".

```js
type A = { a: string };
type B = { b: number };

const toTest = {
  a: {
    func: (arg: A): string => arg.a,
    value: {
      a: "foo"
    }
  },
  b: {
    func: (arg: B): string => `${arg.b}`,
    value: {
      b: 42
    }
  }
} as const;
// toTest is { a: One<A>, b: One<B> }
// so far so good
```

Next step is, select one (by the radio button select) of the value and apply the function to its own value (the real function has a nasty side effect, so I cannot call them all before).
So I tried to create a function for each key and then only call the one linked to the chosen key.

```js
import mapValues from 'lodash-es/mapValues';

// wanted type : Record<keyof typeof toTest, () => string>
const result = mapValues(toTest, <T,>(v: One<T>) => (): string => v.func(v.value));
// result is Dictionary<boolean> ?!?
```

Even if the values inside `result` are good (`console.log` powaaa), the type is a total non-sense.

I tried:

- `mapValues` from lodash/lodash-es
- for ...key of...
- `Object.fromEntries` / `Object.entries`

But I cannot manage to obtain the wanted type (or I receive errors that the types are incompatible)

Any idea?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCAhmAaogNgVwKYGc4BmUEIcA5OhACaK4AWAtHgPRKoY65kDcAUL8AB2MbFAKIAxtjgB5QdgA8AFQB8cAN684hTIIkAuOAApEUAOaGlASjgBeNbhhQhZvtoBuHbJb4BffjAAnmDSAIJ2GnCIho7OgmZwvnxBIXAAQhHqcABGhoKYINmiiXy8EhCCjnAwEEp48LYaWlGGmtraBLoGxqYWcKFWMU4udmq9AHSIADTNHl6ts+3RcABEBBAQK4v+2r4z2rlN7Tp6hibmhmmDcLEj9nAABgAk6hPZvg-77Z5Y3kfHOUMABYAEzbZr+XxRfDlSowUplCpVKB4TDoBoIZBoX64Iw1OqOKZwZRTFRGdyGOSKVQ2e5Ga63eKjODucadPTk8Y-HBWKx8ZjMOAo3Bo+DAfAAEWAEhgwAqpkCCmyG3Q2EQgjUAH4AISa3gCuAAd3VIio1WC0nFcAASthylAqAoANbYQIQAjmkLu6q1epE+nMxlmFRE6AaADaAGk4EI4C63R6Uthvfj6gBdM60hzDeJQsO4UDAdCmfiw3AQVXjShmIzC0V8uAG7l4KIouBmDZUUtIivYKsQGsrOvolZE4cwSb0qy8IA)

Comment: You want to construct new object. `{ a: () => toTest.a.func(toTest.a.value) }` automatically?

Comment: @kennarddh, yes! I successfully constructed the object in the different way I mention, but the type is never accurate)

Comment: Like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIggHgCoD5kDeAUMsjAK4gIBcyAFHFAOa3YCUyAvPgM5hSgmAbhLIAbnAA25CKxEBfImACeABxTYIfHPk4AlCAgD2UACaY+AkEwA06LHlxElalAEEuhZHFqXByeREVdWQAIU8CZAAjWhByAFso6ACRImMQPmQwI01MzkJRHwLSUgoqWgZmWjc2X35-bm9mADo4G1FSCWlZYpLSIoAiGCMjAY6A0Xl20hje0soaekYWMNrkP2sufAADABICZeao+W3pkq6ZWmI+mdoAFgAmccVSRXlvHmRcsEw3AB9QrhUulMlAtORJGBPKgogArQxgZoQcACLR0bLfNjNMGmchITAGYxmCz1aw2OhsbgbJi4XB0BgIBA2ADaAGsIMobBcIABdSm4a7eRlsjk8zgU7jc5plBB0KXctiiMFgchQEBChBEKYEeRsIA?

Comment: @kennarddh, not really. because the way I receive the original toTest, I have, at best a type corresponding to: `Record<"a" | "b", One<A> | One<B>>` (I have and need a strict list of key, so I cannot use the type from Object.entries...reduce) 
So, from an union of the type with generic, I hope to find a type with an union of generic?

Comment: Hmm can you add expected type result?

Comment: @kennarddh, I had a typo, but the wanted type is already there: `// wanted type : Record<keyof typeof toTest, () => string>` (but I added in the playground as well)

Comment: I can solve it but with mapping type https://tsplay.dev/w2kRYN.

Comment: @kennarddh, I can use type assertion too. But it feels weird that this is the only way

Comment: Yeah I also think there is better way but I can only find this way. Can you make an example using type assertion?